# Multiple items appear on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So I got some code from the internet, which makes items animate when they appear on scroll. But the code only triggers one item. How do I make the code trigger all items?

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const p = entry.target.querySelector('p');

    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      p.classList.add('down');
      return; // if we added the class, exit the function
    }

    // We're not intersecting, so remove the class!
    p.classList.remove('down');
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.lol'));
```

```css
@keyframes down {
    0% {
        margin-top: -75px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.down {
    animation: down 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="lol">
        <p>Phasellus efficitur facilisis suscipit. Suspendisse nibh urna, tincidunt non turpis non, consectetur porttitor
        diam. Nulla quis tellus a lorem accumsan placerat. Cras euismod nulla ac bibendum lacinia. In at ex lacus.
        Praesent nisl eros, ultricies et neque non, dapibus iaculis mauris. Curabitur sodales vehicula lorem. In et arcu
        tristique, maximus ligula sit amet, laoreet libero. Aenean sit amet metus eget tellus bibendum tincidunt eget
        vitae tortor. Vivamus at dolor varius, posuere neque id, volutpat velit. Quisque id aliquam arcu. Sed mollis
        elit lacus, eu volutpat mi commodo id. Aenean pretium faucibus ullamcorper. Vestibulum ultrices enim nulla, sed
        aliquet augue maximus sed.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="lol">
        <p>Phasellus efficitur facilisis suscipit. Suspendisse nibh urna, tincidunt non turpis non, consectetur porttitor
        diam. Nulla quis tellus a lorem accumsan placerat. Cras euismod nulla ac bibendum lacinia. In at ex lacus.
        Praesent nisl eros, ultricies et neque non, dapibus iaculis mauris. Curabitur sodales vehicula lorem. In et arcu
        tristique, maximus ligula sit amet, laoreet libero. Aenean sit amet metus eget tellus bibendum tincidunt eget
        vitae tortor. Vivamus at dolor varius, posuere neque id, volutpat velit. Quisque id aliquam arcu. Sed mollis
        elit lacus, eu volutpat mi commodo id. Aenean pretium faucibus ullamcorper. Vestibulum ultrices enim nulla, sed
        aliquet augue maximus sed.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="lol">
        <p>Phasellus efficitur facilisis suscipit. Suspendisse nibh urna, tincidunt non turpis non, consectetur porttitor
        diam. Nulla quis tellus a lorem accumsan placerat. Cras euismod nulla ac bibendum lacinia. In at ex lacus.
        Praesent nisl eros, ultricies et neque non, dapibus iaculis mauris. Curabitur sodales vehicula lorem. In et arcu
        tristique, maximus ligula sit amet, laoreet libero. Aenean sit amet metus eget tellus bibendum tincidunt eget
        vitae tortor. Vivamus at dolor varius, posuere neque id, volutpat velit. Quisque id aliquam arcu. Sed mollis
        elit lacus, eu volutpat mi commodo id. Aenean pretium faucibus ullamcorper. Vestibulum ultrices enim nulla, sed
        aliquet augue maximus sed.</p>
    </div>
```

Only the top paragraph is doing the animation, I want all paragraphs to appear on scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only thing that is getting observed is `document.querySelector('.lol')`. As the `.querySelector` method returns the first element that matches the given CSS selector; only the first element with the `.lol` classname is getting observed.
A simple way to observe all the `.lol` elements is by using the `.querySelectorAll` method and looping through the returned nodeList:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".lol").forEach( element => {
    observer.observe(element);
} );
```

The next problem is that the page height is adjusted on element observation. This will cause for a buggy screen as the page height is non-stop changing. A simple fix is to keep the page height the same by not changing the margin and just move the elements by using the CSS `transform` property:

```
@keyframes down {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-75px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```